# Reducing HttpWebRequest time or reading website line by line backwards

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

### Orginal Question

I am writing a remote connection for a game server. It needs to read the log files to determine what is happening in the server. I have written a method to read the log file. This currently takes 7720ms to complete.

```
    private string getlog()
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(logFileLocation);
        webRequest.UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/html";
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        string responseData;
        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return responseData;
    }
```

I am trying to reduce the time that this method runs. Now the file it is getting is about 7000 line long starting from the oldest information. And I won't need the old information at all, so I'm reading it for no reason. Is there a way to read the file line by line backwards. Or are there ways I can speed up this method?

---

### EDIT

Code is now

```
    private string getlog()
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(logFileLocation);
        webRequest.UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/html";
        webRequest.Proxy = null; //Thanks to tsandy
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        string responseData;
        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return responseData;
    }
```

Comment: you're trying to read the log file remotely? e.g. the file is on server X and the above code is on server Y? then there's no way to read "backwards" via http. you'd need to have something on server X that can spit out the log backwards.

Comment: First of all, yes, reading files backwards is a server-side work. Second of all, there is no way that 7k lines of text take that much time to be delivered nowadays, there is something else wrong in your environment, e.g thin overloaded connection, overloaded server, blocked access to the log file. Also there are some things you can make on client-side like reading line by line using yield, setting proxy-detection off and a lot of other stuff.

Comment: I server is gameservers.com so I don't really have access to it. I am assume they would have everything in line on their side.

Comment: @maiksaray Can you provide a link to " lot of other stuff. "

Comment: Can I maybe start reading line by line half way through

Comment: I can't quickly find a single link, but try using `async`, play with `request.Credentials`, `request.ServicePoint`, also does browser work that slow? try imitating browser(User-agent, get-params, cookies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proxy auto-detect is slow- try `webRequest.Proxy = null;`

Comment: Thanks I will try this when I get home

Comment: This seems to have shorten the time to 5777ms which is a lot faster. So I've added this in. I'll leave this question open to see if another answer to speed things up more will come.